# Response JSON format changing depending on success/error: why?

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-web-api, httpresponse

I'm building a Web Api, using an Ajax call to test an action for uploading files.

The Ajax looks just like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    url: './Customer/' + self.uploadCustomer() + '/Upload',
    data: formData,
    headers: headers,
    success: function (result) {
        self.result(JSON.stringify(result));
    },
    error: function (result) {
        self.result(JSON.stringify(result));
    }
});
```

In my action, I want to return a JSON custom object if there's an error, such as:

```
return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new ResultError(ErrorCode.CustomerNotFound)));
```

which returns exactly the following, as it should

```
{
    "Errors": [
        {
            "Message": "Customer doesn't exist or access is forbidden.",
            "Code": 201
        }
    ]
}
```

But if instead of using `HttpStatusCode.OK` I use any other, such as `HttpStatusCode.NotFound` in exactly the same call that I have above:

```
return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, new ResultError(ErrorCode.CustomerNotFound)));
```

I get this result instead:

```
{
    "readyState":4,
    "responseText":"{\"Errors\":[{\"Message\":\"Customer doesn't exist or access is forbidden.\",\"Code\":201}]}",
    "responseJSON":{"Errors":[{"Message":"Customer doesn't exist or access is forbidden.","Code":201}]},
    "status":404,
    "statusText":"Not Found"
}
```

Why? And how do I get rid of it?

Comment: That's how `Request.CreateResponse` Working. If your `HttpStatusCode` not `OK` it wrap your response with this structure. What do you expect to get?

Comment: @teo van kot As I said, I expect both responses to be formatted in the same way. They are not. `Request.CreateResponse` returns a different JSON depending on `HttpStatusCode`, and I would like to know a) why? b) how to change it?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **result.responseText** or **result.responseJSON** according to your response content type. Because the 'result' is just **response body** for success event but **response body** + **other response related properties** for the error state.

PS: $.ajax's success event only satisfies with HTTP/200 results and for the other reponse codes, it causes the error event fire.

Comment: Well explained and after making the following change it works as expected: `error: function (result) { self.result(JSON.stringify(result.responseJSON)); }`. Thanks!